# Is USSD is not yet supported on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have seen this question so many times and has the answer of **USSD is not yet supported on Android**. But those questions are asked **long time ago**. I just want to know if this feature is still not supported on android? I want to develop an application that can send USSD commands and get the response withing the application. Is it capable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [ticket](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285) is still open. However, you can use [this](http://codepaste.ru/7545/) class to parse USSD answers from the logs.